# Reduce/Filter array of objects into new array of objects.

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter, ecmascript-6

Suppose I have array of objects, I need to create new one array of objects with data from previous. In my case I need filter no all data. What is the best solution with ES6.

```
data = [{
 deviceId:1
 deviceStatus:"Offline"
 deviceType:"Tag"
 isConfigured:true
 isEnabled:true
 isLocalized:false
 isMasterAssigned:false
 lastAliveMessage:null
 location:{roomId: 5, name: "Room_207", zones: null, plan: null}
 name:"Tag For sending an alarm"
},{
 deviceId:2
 deviceStatus:"Online"
 deviceType:"Tag"
 isConfigured:true
 isEnabled:true
 isLocalized:false
 isMasterAssigned:false
 lastAliveMessage:null
 location:{roomId: 6, name: "Room_208", zones: null, plan: null}
 name:"Some Text"
}]
```

I need to filtered only needed data.

```
filteredData=[{
     deviceId:2
     deviceStatus:"Online"
     deviceType:"Tag"
     lastAliveMessage:null
     name: 'name:"Some Text'
     location: location.name
},{
     deviceId:2
     deviceStatus:"Online"
     deviceType:"Tag"
     lastAliveMessage:null
     name: 'name:"Some Text'
     location: location.name
}]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [**Array#map**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) function to iterate over them and create another type of objects.

```js
const data = [{
    deviceId:1,
    deviceStatus:"Offline",
    deviceType:"Tag",
    isConfigured:true,
    isEnabled:true,
    isLocalized:false,
    isMasterAssigned:false,
    lastAliveMessage:null,
    location:{roomId: 5, name: "Room_207", zones: null, plan: null},
    name:"Tag For sending an alarm"
},{
    deviceId:2,
    deviceStatus:"Online",
    deviceType:"Tag",
    isConfigured:true,
    isEnabled:true,
    isLocalized:false,
    isMasterAssigned:false,
    lastAliveMessage:null,
    location:{roomId: 6, name: "Room_208", zones: null, plan: null},
    name:"Some Text"
}];

const newObj = data.map(item => ({
  deviceId: item.deviceId,
  deviceStatus: item.deviceStatus,
  deviceType: item.deviceType,
  lastAliveMessage: item.lastAliveMessage,
  name: item.name,
  location: item.location.name
}));

console.log(newObj);
```

Comment: This question should be marked as a duplicate.

Comment: So vote to close it instead of commenting on an answer @Alexandru-IonutMihai

Answer (score 0):

You could take a white list for the wanted keys.

```js
var data = [{ deviceId: 1, deviceStatus: "Offline", deviceType: "Tag", isConfigured: true, isEnabled: true, isLocalized: false, isMasterAssigned: false, lastAliveMessage: null, location: { roomId: 5, name: "Room_207", zones: null, plan: null }, name: "Tag For sending an alarm" }, { deviceId: 2, deviceStatus: "Online", deviceType: "Tag", isConfigured: true, isEnabled: true, isLocalized: false, isMasterAssigned: false, lastAliveMessage: null, location: { roomId: 6, name: "Room_208", zones: null, plan: null }, name: "Some Text" }], 
    keys = ['deviceId', 'deviceStatus'],
    result = data.map(o => Object.assign(...keys.map(k => ({ [k]: o[k] }))));

console.log(result);
```