# How to build a new object from another nested object

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object

I have a large Object with similar structure as below.

```
[
  {
    "Name": "xxx",
    "Company": "Google",
    "Type": "Search",

  },
  {
    "Name": "yyy",
    "Company": "MS",
    "Type": "Search",
  }
]
```

I am trying to get fields such as Name, Type and I want to build a new Object.

```
var newArray = [];
newArray.push = [ { 
object[0].Name,
object[0].Type } ]
```

Like this but is there any way I can achieve this by using iterations ?

Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reduce/Filter array of objects into new array of objects.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46070246/reduce-filter-array-of-objects-into-new-array-of-objects) and [From an array of objects, extract value of a property as array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19590865) and [javascript extract certain properties from all objects in array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52153345)

Answer (score 2):

You can use [**map**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and take the desired keys and build a new object with desired key and value

```js
let obj = [{"Name": "xxx","Company": "Google","Type": "Search",},{"Name": "yyy","Company": "MS","Type": "Search",}]

let op =obj.map(({Name,Type}) => ({Name,Type}))

console.log(op)
```

Comment: `map` works even when object output is from `JSON.Stringify` ?

Comment: @rɑːdʒɑ you can `JSON.parse` and than access `map`

Answer (score 1):

You could take the wanted property.

```js
var source = [{ Name: "xxx", Company: "Google", Type: "Search" }, { Name: "yyy", Company: "MS", Type: "Search" }],
    target = source.map(({ Name, Type }) => ({ Name, Type }));
    
console.log(target);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Or take the unwanted properties and the rest.

```js
var source = [{ Name: "xxx", Company: "Google", Type: "Search" }, { Name: "yyy", Company: "MS", Type: "Search" }],
    target = source.map(({ Company, ...rest }) => rest);
    
console.log(target);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `map`:

```js
const data = [{"Name": "xxx","Company": "Google","Type": "Search",},{"Name": "yyy","Company": "MS","Type": "Search"}];
const obj = data.map(({ Name, Type }) => ({ Name, Type }));
console.log(obj);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: auto; }
```